# change color from text except everything is between tags <b>

Tags: css

How to change the color only from text except everything is between tags ?

Sample text:

```
<b>A7</b>      <b>D</b>
this is a test
<b>A7+</b>      <b>G9</b>
this is a test
```

Comment: You forgot to post the jQuery you tried.

Comment: This is really a CSS question

Comment: CSS http://jsfiddle.net/KJ9j7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that all of that text is wrapped in a parent element (I've used `<div>`, but almost any other element would suffice), as such:

```
<div>
    <b>A7</b>
    <b>D</b>
    this is a test
    <b>A7+</b>
    <b>G9</b>
    this is a test
</div>
```

Then you can't change "all the text except the `<b>` tags", because CSS won't allow you to style the text without affecting the colour of the the `<b>` elements, you can, however, style the `div` and then 'unstyle' the `b` elements:

```
div {
    color: #f00;
}

div b {
    color: #000;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/7QJLG/1/).

To do this with jQuery (and, honestly, from the information you've posted jQuery seems unnecessary), you'd have to create wrapping elements for each of the strings of characters that are not wrapped in `b` elements and then directly style, or add a class to, those elements:

```
$('body').contents().filter(function(){
    return this.nodeType === 3 && this.nodeValue.trim().length > 0;
}).wrap('<span />').parent().css('color','red');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/7QJLG/).

References:

- [`contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/).
- [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
- [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/).
- [`wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/).

Comment: Thank David. It's exactly I wanted!

Comment: In which case, I'm glad to have been of help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
body{color:red;}
b{color:black;}
```

[**Fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/L9DkE/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery like this:

```
$('body').css('color', '#FFCCFF');
$('b').css('color', '#000000');
```

But if you can do it in CSS it would be better:

```
body {
    color: #FFCCFF;
}

b {
    #000000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged this as `jquery`, I just provided a solution for this with jquery, You may `wrap` the html which was written by you in a `paragraph` tag like below. And then you have to use the [.addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) function of Jquery to set different `classes` with different colours for that both `paragraph` and `bold` tag.

### HTML

```
<p><b>A7</b><b>D</b>
this is a test
<b>A7+</b><b>G9</b>
this is a test</p>
```

### CSS

```
.Paragraph{
    color:red;
}

.boldtext{
    color:black;
}
```

### JQUERY

```
$('p').addClass('Paragraph');
$('p > b').addClass("boldtext");
```

---

### [DEMONSTRATION](http://jsfiddle.net/7JeqE/)